# SSMS 2008 / 2014 showing different values for TempDB file sizes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, tempdb

Here's a fun one.  Last week I reconfigured the initial file sizes in our tempdb database to 1GB each.  We had an event a few weeks back that locked up our server due to a table with no indexes getting absolutely hammered.  This caused our 3 of our tempdb files to grow.  I re-sized them using SSMS 2014 and they should have reset to their configured size this past Sunday when we rebooted the server.  They didn't and now I'm seeing a difference in the information SSMS is returning for those files.

Our server is 2008 R2, here are the different SSMS views:

**2008:**

[image]

**2014:**

[image]

**Here are the files as they currently sit on the server itself:**

[image]

It seems that SSMS 2014 is returning the correct information, but SSMS 2008 is not.  Is this a known issue that anyone has seen before?  If so, what's causing it?  Does 2014 attempt to store this information differently than 2008 R2 and negate the 2008 configured values?

Now, there were no auto-grow events that happened once the server was restarted (checked the default  trace and there were no events)  Given this information, what do you think my best course of action is to get these files re-sized appropriately.  I'm totally fine with growing all the files to 2GB but those tempdb files are hardly being used (<5% usage on all of them).

The servers are not on fire or anything and production is running fine but we definitely want all those tempdb files configured to the same size.

**EDIT: Result of requested query**

[image]

Comment: Does the instance have trace flag 1117 and 1118 turned on?  1117 ensures files grow at the same rate.  It sure *looks* like these files aren't growing at the same rate.  I realize you said in your question there were no growth events, however, there clearly has been some growth on 'tempdb15' and 'tempdb16'.

Comment: Currently, both of those trace flags are disabled.  Would that not allow me to see if there were any autogrow events?

Comment: Just added to the bottom for ya.

Comment: Isn't that trace flag instance-wide, though?  Not confined only to the scope of the database? Also, in running the query provided by your link, it's only returning information on master, not on any other DBs.

Comment: Yes, TF1117 is instance wide.  There is an open connect item to have Microsoft setup a flag for just the tempdb, here:  https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/781198/trace-flag-1117-autogrowth-of-data-files-is-instance-wide-would-like-a-flag-for-just-tempdb

Comment: The results are the same in 2008 and 2014.  Just baffling that SSMS GUI is showing different values. Any insight into that one?

Comment: I'm not certain but it is possible the SSMS 2014 interface is getting the *current* values for the file sizes, instead of the configured values.  The query I had you run looks at the *configured* values.

Comment: Alright, gonna have to do some more digging on this one.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be certain you are configuring `tempdb` file sizes as *intended*, you should use T-SQL instead of the SSMS user interface.

To resize files, you can use something like this:

```
ALTER DATABASE tempdb
MODIFY FILE (NAME=tempdev, SIZE=1GB, GROWTH=1GB);
```

You'd need to execute this once for each logical file in tempdb.  `NAME=tempdev_2`, `NAME=tempdev_3` etc.

I'd suggest using a T-SQL query to obtain information about the file sizes, as in:

```
SELECT DatabaseName = d.name
    , DBFileName = mf.name
    , DBInitialSize = mf.size
    , Growth = mf.growth
    , GrowthIsPercentage = mf.is_percent_growth
    , FileType = mf.type_desc
FROM master.sys.master_files mf
    INNER JOIN master.sys.databases d ON mf.database_id = d.database_id
WHERE d.name = 'tempdb'
ORDER BY d.name, mf.name;
```

As mentioned in the comments, you should certainly look into the possibility of using Trace Flag 1117 and 1118, if you are concerned about `tempdb` performance; ostensibly this is the root-cause of your questions about `tempdb`.

Aaron Bertrand has a great article about using the SSMS Interface vs T-SQL at:

- https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/14/bad-habits-to-kick-using-the-visual-designers